# Check how many Fibonacci numbers exists between 1 and N

Tags: c

Using this program I can easily get the sequence of Fibonacci numbers.

```
int main(){

int n,i,first=0,second=1,next=0,fib=0;

// 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34

printf("Enter the value of N: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=1;i<=n;i++){


    next = first+second;
    first = second;
    second = next;

    printf("%d",next);


}
```

}

But how to get the many febonacci numbers are there.

Example if I enter 35 then result should show 10 febonacci numbers.

Comment: This is _super easy_ to do. You want to _count_ these numbers, so you need another variable to do this...

Comment: Tried this, but didn't work: 
if(next == i)
        fib = fib+1;

Comment: https://oeis.org/A108852 might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
  int main(){

    int n,i,first=0,second=1,next=0,fib=0;

    // 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34

    printf("Enter the value of N: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;next<=n;i++){
        next = first+second;
        first = second;
        second = next;
    }
printf("%d",i);

}
```

Thanks to VHS

Comment: Then please "accept" that answer: there is a checkbox for you to show your thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop is running for `n` number of iterations rather than running until `next` exceeds `n`. See the following revision in your code:

```
int main(){

  int n,count=2,first=0,second=1,next=0,fib=0;

  // 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34

  printf("Enter the value of N: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  while((first+second) <= n){      
      next = first+second;
      first = second;
      second = next;    
      printf("%d",next); 
      count++;
  }
  printf("found %d numbers ", count);
}
```

Comment: But I don't want the series, I just want how many numbers are on that series. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you don't want the series, comment out the statement `printf("%d",next); `

Comment: Let me clear. If I enter 36 on the program, it will give me 10 because there are only 10 fibonnaci number between 1 and 36.

Comment: Just run the above snippet. Comment out the `printf("%d",next);`. It will only print the count. So in your example of 36 as the input, it will print `found 10 numbers`.

Comment: It returns 8 :(

Comment: I have edited to initialize the count to 2 instead of 0. Run it again. I realize that a Fibonacci series always has first 2 numbers (0 and 1).